# How to use asian font (specifically STSongStd-Light) with apache pdfbox to generate a pdf document?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have an existing piece of code in Java using the older version of third-party library iText to generate a pdf with asian text using asian font.

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("STSongStd-Light", "UniGB-UCS2-H", NOT_EMBEDDED);
content.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 15);
```

I now want to do the same using apache pdfbox as the iText thing requires licensing etc.
Does anyone know if this is achievable using apache pdfbox?

So far, I have found https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/Adobe-GB1#since-the-2000-11-30supplement-4version mentioning that StSong font is supported in Adobe-GB1 and also found this method called getCIDFont https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/FontMapper.html that might be able to do this. But, I am not exactly able to figure out how to do this.

```
# Not sure how these dictionaries should look like?
COSDictionary type0fontdescriptor = new COSDictionary();
COSDictionary fontdescriptor = new COSDictionary();
PDCIDFontType2 pdcidFontType2 = new PDCIDFontType2(fontdescriptor, new PDType0Font(type0fontdescriptor), null);
TrueTypeFont ttf = pdcidFontType2.getTrueTypeFont();
# Not sure what encoding should be used
PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.load(document, ttf, Encoding.getInstance(COSName.STANDARD_ENCODING));
```

I have also found the ttf file for this font over here https://github.com/asmpg/AwesomeUtils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/asomepig/tika/STSong-Light.ttf. Not sure what if we need any license to use it though. But, even when I try to load the ttf to see if we can render there's an exception thrown like this.

```
PDFont font =
        PDTrueTypeFont.load(
            document,
            new File(basePath + "ttfs/STSong-Light.ttf"),
            Encoding.getInstance(COSName.STANDARD_ENCODING));

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: head is mandatory
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:197)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:165)
    at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:91)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.load(PDTrueTypeFont.java:93)
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's the best way to use StSong font with apache pdfbox? Is it even possible?

Comment: That isn't a TrueType font.

Answer (score 0):

Font from https://www.wfonts.com/font/stsong worked.

`PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("//path/to/ttf/chinese.stsong.ttf"));`

Couldn't find any licensing info from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts.